# Can I create several levels of nested objects?

Tags: javascript

Working on a project where I need to create an object containing several data sets that each have their own subsequent data sets. Not sure if this is excessive but I need to be able to accomplish something along these lines.

Here's an example of what I mean, this doesn't work but it should give an idea:

```
var menu = {
    "appetizers": {
        soup: {
            num1: "beef",
            num2: "chicken",
            num3: "vegetarian": {
                v1: "soy",
                v2: "tomato",
            };
        },
        "salad": {
            sal1: "apple",
            sal2: "egg",
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, `;` should be `,` on line 9, and it's unclear what the meaning of `num3: "vegetarian": {` is supposed to be. But in general, the property value can be any expression, including another object literal. There is no special syntax for that, you just nest the object literals.

Comment: Smells like a dupe.

Comment: I'd post an answer, but "Yes." is too short and the site won't accept it.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, I resolved it. Just a mistake with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at the object below. You can do something like that.

Only remember that objects are key value pairs and so for that it has to be in the form of:

```
{key1:value1, 
 key2:{valueKey: valueValue}
}
```

Hence the following works:

```js
var menu = {
"appetizers": {
    "soup": {
        "num1": "beef",
        "num2": "chicken",
        "num3": "vegetarian",
        "num4": {
            "v1": "soy",
            "v2": "tomato",
        }
    },

    "salad": {
        "sal1": "apple",
        "sal2": "egg",
    }

}

};

console.log(menu);
```